# Different rounding behaviour (less precision) for the same double sum code with the same inputs in a different program

Tags: c#, x86, double, precision, x87

Visual Studio 2017 .Net 4.7.2 x86

In one large application, we have a problem with a simple addition of double, which is not a double precision problem to solve because the same code works in another application or in another part of the large application.

**Edit:** See the C# + corresponding assembly code (right click in VS go to disassembly)

bad code :

```
                    {
15B185FB  nop  
                        double aa = 44537.5703125d;
15B185FC  fld         dword ptr ds:[15B188F8h]  
15B18602  fstp        qword ptr [ebp-11Ch]   // [ebp-11Ch] = 44537.5703125
                        double bb = aa + 120 / (3600.0 * 24.0);
15B18608  fld         qword ptr [ebp-11Ch]  // [ebp-11Ch] = 44537.5703125
15B1860E  fadd        qword ptr ds:[15B18900h]  // 15B18900h = 0.0013888888888888889
15B18614  fstp        qword ptr [ebp-124h]  //[ebp-124h] = 44537.570312500000
                    }
15B1861A  nop
```

good code:

```
                double newMinimum = 44537.5703125d;
01870997  fld         dword ptr ds:[18709E8h]  // 0x009D09E8 => float 44537.5703
0187099D  fstp        qword ptr [ebp-48h]  // 44537.570312500000
                double newMaximum = newMinimum + 120 / (3600.0 * 24.0);
018709A0  fld         qword ptr [ebp-48h]  // [ebp-48h] = 44537.570312500000
018709A3  fadd        qword ptr ds:[18709F0h]  // 18709F0h = 0.0013888888888888889
018709A9  fstp        qword ptr [ebp-50h]  // [ebp-50h] = 44537.571701388886
```

The bad result sum is 44537.5703125, like the operation was done with float precision.

**Edit** after @PeterCordes Answer :
Now I can make a minimal repetition bug:

```
using SharpDX.Direct3D9;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BugDoublePrecision
{
    class Bug
    {
        public static void Test(IntPtr handle)
        {
            
            precisionTest();

            PresentParameters presentParameters = new PresentParameters()
            {
                Windowed = true,
                SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
                EnableAutoDepthStencil = true,
                AutoDepthStencilFormat = Format.D16,
                MultiSampleType = MultisampleType.FourSamples
            };

            var device = new Device(new Direct3D(), 0, DeviceType.Hardware, handle,
                CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing /*| CreateFlags.FpuPreserve*/, presentParameters);

            precisionTest(); //failed if FpuPreserve it not used


        }

        private static void precisionTest()
        {            
            double aa = 44537.5703125d;
            double bb = aa + 120 / (3600.0 * 24.0);
            if (aa == bb)
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like C#...

Comment: @Llama Actually it is C#, but interleaved with assembly

Comment: @DavidG Oh, you're right. I didn't notice the `double blah = something;` bits.

Comment: Yes sorry I post assembly code with C# code, because code is exactly the same ! the assembler also apart from the addresses.

Comment: @TheGeneral Despite many attempts I have not been able to isolate this problem in a simple program, because I never  see that, do you think I have to post a Issues there https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the question. You're complaining about c#, but the code you show is not c#...

Comment: @ZoharPeled ok I edit the post,  t's unbelievable but it's c#

Comment: Perhaps something set the x87 FPU's precision control to 24-bit mantissa precision; apparently D3D9 could do that on Windows: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/intermediate-floating-point-precision/  It's the same asm both times, right? (other than the locations of the locals within the stack frame.)  So it will behave the same with the same inputs, other than rounding mode and precision control.  If you can, ditch obsolete x87 and have your compiler use SSE2 for scalar `double` math like it would in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes We use D3D9, so it must be that! I will check that as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same asm both times, right? (other than the locations of the locals within the stack frame.) So it will behave the same with the same inputs, other than rounding mode and precision control.

**One possible explanation is that something set the x87 FPU's precision control to 24-bit mantissa precision** (same as `float` but still with the full exponent range); apparently D3D9 did/does do that on Windows because it makes `fsqrt` a bit faster.  Bruce Dawson explains in an article from his *excellent* series on floating point theory and practice with a focus on x86, especially Windows: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/intermediate-floating-point-precision/

(BTW, the x87 precision/rounding control register is a per-thread thing, but IDK how its inherited when starting new threads.  Apparently "initializing D3D" is where the offending code runs (perhaps via a native-code interface from C#); if you reset the x87 FPU after that e.g. `finit`, you should be back to full intermediate precision. (via another native-code call).  Or set it to 53-bit mantissa precision to avoid multiple rounding steps in computations that do involve storing to double-precision, just always round everything to that mantissa width like you would with SSE2 using `double`.)

If you can, ditch obsolete x87 and have your compiler use SSE2 for scalar double math like it would in 64-bit mode.  It has separate math instructions for float vs. double, instead of converting on load/store.  SSE2 is baseline for x86-64, and existed on P4; the oldest mainstream CPUs without it are Athlon XP, although AMD Geode ultra-low-power CPUs don't have SIMD at all.